# Using ReadonlyMap<K, V> type

Tags: javascript, typescript, collections, immutability

TypeScript defines `ReadonlyMap<K, V>` interface which is immutable version of standard JavaScript `Map<K, V>` type.

How are we supposed to use `ReadonlyMap<K, V>` in our code?

It's not derived from anything and doesn't declare constructor. So, is it true that we just should do:

```
public publicApiMethod(): ReadonlyMap<K, V> {
    const map: Map<K, V> = new Map(...);
    return map as ReadonlyMap<K, V>;
}
```

Or there are a better approaches to using `ReadonlyMap<K, V>` rather than just typecasting?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Short answer: you're doing it right.

[`ReadonlyMap<K, V>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1416053b9e85ca2344a7a6aa10456d633ea1cd65/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts#L38-L43) is essentially a *supertype* of [`Map<K, V>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1416053b9e85ca2344a7a6aa10456d633ea1cd65/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts#L1-L29) since the methods and properties it does have match up with those of `Map<K,V>`.  So by returning a `Map` as a `ReadonlyMap`, all you're doing is widening the type of the value.   By the way, that means you can skip the type assertion:

```
public publicApiMethod(): ReadonlyMap<K, V> {
    const map: Map<K, V> = new Map(...);
    return map; // no assertion necessary
}
```

Just like you could do this:

```
public anotherMethod(): string | number {
    return "hey"; // always "hey", but assignable to string | number
}
```

The benefit is that a caller is not free to assume that the returned value has any of the other `Map` methods, and trying to set or clear the map contents will produce a compile time error, despite the fact that those methods would indeed exist at runtime.  (Or for the `anotherMethod()` example, the caller cannot know that the return value is always a `string` and can't directly call any string-specific methods on it.)

This compile-time prohibition of runtime behavior is similar to the way the [`readonly` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#readonly) works.  When a property is `readonly`, TypeScript will complain if you try to modify it, even though the modification would succeed at runtime.

You could, if you wanted, implement your own version of `ReadonlyMap` that is read-only even at runtime, but that's only worth the effort if you have a use case that requires it.  If you don't, (and you probably don't) then don't worry about it and keep doing it the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

To feel safe yourself at compile time, we may use like that:

```
public publicApiMethod(): ReadonlyMap<K, V> {
    const map: Map<K, V> = new Map(...);
    ...
    return map; // no need casting
}
```

To feel safe yourself at runtime, we may use like that:

```
public publicApiMethod(): ReadonlyMap<K, V> {
    const map: Map<K, V> = new Map(...);
    ...

    const trueRuntimeReadonlyMap: ReadonlyMap<string, string> = Object.freeze({
        entries: map.entries.bind(map),
        forEach: map.forEach.bind(map),
        get: map.get.bind(map),
        has: map.has.bind(map),
        keys: map.keys.bind(map),
        size: map.size,
        values: map.values.bind(map),
        [Symbol.iterator]: map[Symbol.iterator].bind(map)
    });

    return trueRuntimeReadonlyMap;
}
```