# Why `map.has()` doesn't act as a type guard

Tags: typescript

I faced the following problem: In my application I have a `Map` in which a set of lambda functions are paired with some `Role`s. Each lambda takes a `secondParameter` and returns a `settings` object.

```
enum Role {
    ROLE_1 = "role"
}
const settingsRole1 = {}
const defaultSettings = {}
const secondParameter = ""

const map = new Map<Role, (secondParameter: string) => any>([
    [Role.ROLE_1, (secondParameter: string) => settingsRole1]
]);
const settings = map.get(Role.ROLE_1)(secondParameter) ?? defaultSettings;
```

I received this error while trying to calling the function returning from the map: `TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'`.
I tried to guard it as shown below, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
const settings = map.has(Role.ROLE_1) ? map.get(Role.ROLE_1)(secondParameter) : defaultSettings;
```

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76804217/cannot-invoke-value-of-map-because-possibly-undefined?noredirect=1#comment135401537_76804217), it seems that using the `optional chaining operator` works, so the following snippet implements a working guard

```
const settings = map.get(Role.ROLE_1)?.(secondParameter) ?? defaultSettings;
```

Why does the guard build using the `optional chaining operator` work, while the one built with `if map.has()` does not?

Comment: The optional chaining method gets the value from the Map, and then checks if it is nullish; the Map itself is finished with by the time that check is performed. **It is checking the value.** With `.has()`, it is checking if the value is in the Map; **it is affecting the type of the Map itself** (not actually, but conceptually). TS does not change the type of the Map after a check with `.has()`, so following accesses of the Map do not remember that result.

Comment: There was a request on the TS repo for a way for class methods to modify the type of their instance (or something to that effect; like a type guard, but retyping `this` instead of just a regular arg), but I don't know if it would apply here. And it's either an open request or declined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`has()` method on `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) doesn't act as a [type guard method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) on the `Map` instance.  So calling `map.has(x)` has no [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) effect on `map`, and therefore cannot affect subsequent calls to  `map.get(x)`.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#13086](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086) to support this, but it hasn't been implemented because, at least for a mutable, non-`ReadonlyMap` (see [Using ReadonlyMap<K, V> type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50046573/2887218) ), the fact that `map.has(x)` is `true` now doesn't mean it will be `true` forever.  As [mentioned by the TS team dev lead in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086#issuecomment-524123373): "This much, much, much, *much* more tricky than it looks because you also have to define how *long* the `has` check should last."

Any change to accomodate this would need to act correctly in both `map.get()` lines below:

```
const map = new Map([[1, { a: 1 }], [3, { a: 2 }]]);
if (map.has(2)) {
    map.get(2).a; // should be okay
    map.delete(2);
    map.get(2).a; // should not be okay
}
```

Right now it errors on both of them, which is annoying, but safe.

You could merge in your own type guard for `has()` if you want, maybe like this:

```
interface NarrowableMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
    has<P extends K>(k: P): this is { get(p: P): V } & this;
}
```

but then it would fail to error on both of them, which is convenient, but unsafe, especially on that second line.

```
const map = new Map([[1, { a: 1 }], [3, { a: 2 }]]) as
    NarrowableMap<number, { a: number }>;

if (map.has(2)) {
    map.get(2).a; // no error, that's good
    map.delete(2);
    map.get(2).a; // no error, that's bad
}
```

The language currently doesn't have a way to mark methods as resetting control flow narrowing.  This happens automatically on property reassignment and the `delete` keyword, but map operations don't trigger this.

So that's why it doesn't work.

---

The easiest refactoring is to give up on `has`-then-`get` and switch to `get`-then-validate.  So you can do it like this:

```
const v = map.get(2);
if (v !== undefined) { v.a }
```

Or you could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to make it more concise:

```
const w = v?.a
const x = map.get(2)?.a
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4wLwzAUwO4wLLIAUA2sQIwA0MA3jAgFwxkwC+AulcQMxW0MwAmVmzYBKANwBYAFABLAGYxCiJADoAFggiEBo0TRkwj8ZKoDmmKDtGqE4mAHoHMCOpABXADYATGACNMGBAAawQAT0NjFVVvTE9LTGspaWMTNQsrXVt7Jxc3L18wEFgAoNCI6RYZGVkwKEwAJ3kEYECAOQQGhpBsBD94giQAHgBpKgA1AD4YTAAPerBvCHxkUYnp6kijTQghgAUZ+cxF5ZHJwmDGPdFGKHVZZYeaGAzCJCubmHHWGAAyGDuD2SVWkMjACDgmAgSBa7U63WwmF8m1BKWMoEgsBUaAwOBWSBI5F4dEYzHYnB4z34QnYYjoEC2qRgHS6PT6A1WYHccACDWJ-C5PMarEmyVSCiU0R21n0KKZUVMryydkZqWisXi9SSqoV6Us1myjJBMmN0gx0BgADccdElRIaopCNaAISodDuRaYeS1JGyq22Vgyc2wXDoS0AflsQfAFtmNsV+t0kYQQA)