# How to do you use tuples with generics in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a type safe map object.  I want to define my key/value pairs once and only once.

I have succeeded with the following:

```
const myPropTuple = [
    [0, "cat"],
    [1, "dog"],
    [2, "bird"]
] as const;

type TMyPropKey = TInnerTupple<typeof myPropTuple>[0];
type TMyPropValue = TInnerTupple<typeof myPropTuple>[1];

function getMyProp(val: number) {
    type TKey = TInnerTupple<typeof myPropTuple>[0];

    const mapA2 = new Map(myPropTuple);
    if(!mapA2.has(val as TKey)) throw new RangeError("unexpected value");
    return mapA2.get(val as TKey);
}

// helper library (not to be inlined)
type TTupleType<T extends Iterable<any>> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer R> ? R :never;
type TInnerTupple<I extends Iterable<any>> = TTupleType<I>;

// Tests
console.assert(getMyProp(1) === "dog");
//console.assert(getMyProp(1) === "turle");    // throws compiler error

const a: TMyPropValue = "cat";
//const b: TMyPropValue = "eagle";    // throws compiler error
```

But I would like make the function generic and still maintain type safety:

The goal is to be able to write

```
const myPropTuple = [
    [0, "cat"],
    [1, "dog"],
    [2, "bird"]
] as const;

console.assert(getGenericProp(myPropTuple, 1) === "dog");

const yourPropTuple = [
    [0, "fish"],
    [1, "towel"],
    [2, "whale"]
] as const;

console.assert(getGenericProp(yourPropTuple, 0) === "fish");
```

and for the following to fail to compile

```
console.assert(getGenericProp(myPropTuple, 1) === "turle");    // throws compiler error

type TYourPropValue = TInnerTupple<typeof yourPropTuple>[1];
const y: TYourPropValue = "dog";    // throws compiler error
```

---

**addendum**

---

@jcalz suggested an alternate solution which has the cardinal virtue of simplicity, so I will repeat it here slightly expanded:

```
const animalProps = {
    0: "cat",
    1: "dog",
    2: "bird"
  } as const;

function getGenericProp2<T extends object>(props: T, val: keyof T): T[keyof T] {
    const found = props[val];
    if(found === undefined) throw new RangeError("unexpected value");
    return found;
}
type TValues = ValueOf<typeof animalProps>;
type TKeys = keyof typeof animalProps;
```

Comment: Why not just use a null prototype object?

Comment: I need to use the types of the tuple elements in other statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it this way:

```
function getGenericProp<T extends readonly [any, any]>(
  propTuple: readonly T[], val: T[0]
) {
  const mapA2: Map<T[0], T[1]> = new Map(propTuple);
  if (!mapA2.has(val)) throw new RangeError("unexpected value");
  return mapA2.get(val);
}
```

It is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the *elements* of `propTuple`, which we expect to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [`readonly` 2-tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types). The type of `val` is `T[0]`, one of the first elements of each pair inside `propTuple`.  And the return type is `T[1] | undefined`.  `T[1]` means one of the second elements of each pair inside `propTuple`,  and the `undefined` happens because [`Map.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) can return `undefined` regardless of whether you've checked `has()` first (see [Why `map.has()` doesn't act as a type guard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76804861/2887218).  This was also true of your non-generic version, so addressing it is out of scope here).

Anyway you can verify that it works as desired:

```
const myPropTuple = [
  [0, "cat"],
  [1, "dog"],
  [2, "bird"]
] as const;
console.assert(getGenericProp(myPropTuple, 1) === "dog"); // okay

const yourPropTuple = [
  [0, "fish"],
  [1, "towel"],
  [2, "whale"]
] as const;
console.assert(getGenericProp(yourPropTuple, 0) === "fish"); // okay

console.assert(getGenericProp(myPropTuple, 1) === "turtle"); // error!
// This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 
// '"cat" | "dog" | "bird" | undefined' and '"turtle"' have no overlap.

getGenericProp(myPropTuple, 3) // error!
// Argument of type '3' is not assignable to parameter of type '0 | 2 | 1'.
```

Looks good.

---

Note that the function doesn't know *which* of the outputs are returned for a particular input, and such a thing *would* be possible... but `Map`s aren't really meant for that.  You could try refactoring `Map`'s typings to pay attention to that, as shown in [Typescript: How can I make entries in an ES6 Map based on an object key/value type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907009/2887218), but that suggests instead of a tuple of tuples you really just want an *object*:

```
const obj = {
  0: "cat",
  1: "dog",
  2: "bird"
} as const;
const val = obj[1];
// const val: "dog"
```

but now you don't need a *function* at all, for just an indexing operation.  But this is also out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQOKrKgTjCABVzgAcAeAFUVQA8psATAZ0V1QENGEAbAT0QBtDmD4AaRCL4BdAHwAKAFCJEpEqUohSPVAC42nbmH6JKg6RIBuHHvrMAGaYoCUiAN7LEEBMyiIAthykAIIATPoAskFUgo4SZgCMcogAvIg4AO6IUaTyamSa2qjOANyeMMCI8gCEgSGhAHQAFhzM8tY8zq5QTSRZmYgASiJoAKK4JLjyAETgdKSo0KiMiB0gqNOlnuxQILhIdWENaFDtNlsAvoqK3mC+AXzEBVo6qUKesRLTEBxQ0xYfBJfbjIf5iD6hL4AIxguEY-0U0kkrFuvjKqLgOgarWYeFOJywOHwRHU8n8j3UhR0EgSrhS9MQ0xBmxKiAA9GzEHAANYcPg3Hx+PhwPZPDQvVBvQQfexfYAwZhNMGAr5QOAZVA8ZUqQSQxkZFo6BFI1peQXonyY1DY5i43D49CEvAEMXyYWiykSiT2OkM6byxUs9mcnl8gV3K02u0OzDYZ0kshkinPIo031paa7e1G0rBmgTOC4aqKDmmJoKs3+UgcfDMBCSUgLGusNWIKGS8AwMAMbvwMA2NuLDggXGIHqSqB8BasEucgDk31+00QAB9GczV4yYXDl2vwIxUPKcIw55IwCsF1moEbTy1LJKwHAuffcDwgg15KEAMwANgA7M41wEnGxKuuSYpUqgEhfq4pZ4JMxalsEuDICA-jYH4cCVJOCyIHOX6nhWj5+DiMDIP2UKvK21a4Bw6EMLgXLYVOkpzvYm6hJuCRzh+34ACwAKyAdcqKYVCABWbweCo9j6IufzgioCRycyimIOEW6wvCigXMiZp3FAFoGasA5pHAEmCEkZSlqJJm2OucCgkAA)

Comment: This looks great.  My initial tests show it works and is type safe.  I'll be studying this closely!

Comment: After some study, this is a really fine piece of code and clear exposition.  After some research I found `type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]; type TValues = ValueOf<typeof obj>;`  which allows me to use your suggestion to use a plain object.